# QQ-plot indicates normality of residuals but density plot does not

Tags: mixed-model, qq-plot

My QQ-plot indicates normality (a fairly straight line), but my density plot shows departures from normality. Why is this happening? Is this a big problem for my model?

Here's my model syntax:

```
response ~  block*f_transition* f_manner + (1 + block || id ), 
            data = aggrdata, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead", 
            optCtrl=list(maxfun=200000)))
```

[image]

[image]

Here is also the residuals vs fitted plot

[image]

Comment: What features of the QQ plot lead you to conclude it's "fairly straight"?  It shows significant evidence to the contrary, especially in the tails.  Whether this is a "big problem" depends on your model, so you'll need to provide more information about that.

Comment: I don't know that I would say the density plot departs from normal. There is that one blip around -1, but you can see that in the QQ-plot as well. Regardless, things seem to still be unimodal and roughly symmetric. I don't see why this would be any problem. Have you used a numeric test for normality (i.e. Shapiro-Wilk, etc.)?

Comment: I agree with @whuber. You could say the QQ-plot in not normal in the tails. Do you know anything about the values at the ends (particularly on the high end)? Maybe they could be removed and redo the plots.

Comment: @Todd Burus, I looked at the observed vs fitted values individually and the model just seems to be off for some people. The observed values were not necessarily at the boundaries of my scale. So I'm not sure what is going on.  Furthermore, it seems that my model is estimating outside the scale boundaries. So there are values like 1.05, even though my scale is between 0-1.

Comment: @whuber I am looking at how much money people split out of $1. I am looking at the effects of recipient wealth, income mobility (which is order), and legitimacy of wealth (merit vs luck). What other information would you need?

Comment: Does "looking at" mean estimating the model parameters reliably, making reliable predictions, or something else?

Comment: The plot I first want to see is residuals versus fitted.

Comment: @whuber Making reliable predictions i.e. I'm also looking at p-values. Strangely enough, the credible intervals from a bayesian model don't seem to match the p-values of my lmer model.

Comment: I'm confused by that, because p-values have nothing to do with prediction.

Comment: @Nick Cox, I've added the residuals vs fitted plot to the original post now.

Comment: @whuber I'm pretty new to mixed models so I might not understand all your terms or what you mean by them. What would you suggest in this case? Transforming the data?

Comment: Thanks, but please tell us what the response is? What are the observed minimum and maximum values (and the limits in principle if they are different)?

Comment: @Nick Cox, my scale is between 0-1, with intervals of 0.01. Observed minumum and maximum were also between 0-1. However, the model estimated some values above and below this range. Example, 1.05 or -0.03.

Comment: @whuber, just to give you more details in layman terms. I want to look at whether amount donated would be higher for upwardly mobile (poor to rich) or stably rich people, and whether this interacts with how they received their wealth via merit or via luck.

Comment: I think you need a link function which respects the bounds of the response. Either way, a bounded response rather implies that normal distribution is not strongly appropriate as a reference distribution for the residuals. I can't advise on which R syntax that might mean.

Answer (score 1):

As evident from the comments above, it seems that you have a bounded outcome for which a Beta mixed-effects model would be more appropriate. You can fit such a model, using, for example, the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package I've written. A sample analysis with such a model can be found [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html#beta-mixed-effects-model).

Comment: I fit a beta-binomial model specified here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TailRank/vignettes/betabinomial.pdf. However, the pp_check plots still look quite bad and don't capture all the peaks.

Comment: @user3635550 but did you fit a beta-binomial mixed model?

Comment: @ Dimitris Rizopoulos Yes I did.

Comment: @ Dimitris Rizopoulos unfortunately, looking at your sample analysis, I don't seem to have the skills right not to understand or fit your beta mixed model. I'm just starting out as a student.